# "These are [one/ones] of the foundations..." - which "one" should I use?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, expressions, expression-choice

I'm having a hard time picking between

> These are **one** of the foundations of....

and

> These are **ones** of the foundations of..

Or is there a more idiomatic way to express it?

Comment: These are one of the.. is the correct one.

Comment: These are some of the foundations of ... maybe?

Answer (score 3):

***"This is one of the foundations . . . "*** or

***"These are some of the foundations . . ."***

***"These one"*** is mismatched since "these" implies multiple and "one" is singular

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time picking, too, because of the "..." after the preposition. You've done yourself a bit of a disservice here, because there's not really enough context here to address the question with certainty!

That said,

> *These are the foundations of...
>
>   These are among the foundations of...
>
>   These are foundations of...*

...these are all valid ways to say this, too, but they avoid the very awkward *“These are one”* construct.

<sub>P.S. These are the kind of questions that would be better asked on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) than ELU.</sub>